# Flutter Userinput will only get displayed after a hotreload, but not in the application itself

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

Hi im new to Flutter and coding and tried do build my first to do app. I've created a textformfield to add new todos with a button in a container above. I used the texteditingcontroller to get the userinput and stored the input in a variable. I tried to display the userInput on a toDoSection, but it only appears, if im hot reloading the application. My button, which should do the work instead, doesn't work. What did I do wrong here?

`landing_page.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/presentation/widgets/to_do_section.dart';

 final _textController = TextEditingController();
    String userInput = "";
class LandingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LandingPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LandingPage> createState() => _LandingPageState();
}

class _LandingPageState extends State<LandingPage> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Center(child: Text("To-Do-App")),
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const ToDos(),
            ToDoAdd()
            ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

 

  Column ToDoAdd() {
    return Column(
          children:  [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20),
              child: TextField(
                controller: _textController,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: "Add a new ToDo",
                )  ,
              ),
              
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              color: Colors.redAccent,
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                  userInput = _textController.text; 
                  toDoList.add(userInput);
                  
                });
                  
                },
                child: Text("Admit", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                ),
                Text(userInput)
          ],
        );
  }


}
```

`to_do_section.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/presentation/widgets/landing_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/responsive_layout.dart';

var toDoList = <String> [userInput];
class ToDos extends StatefulWidget {
  
  const ToDos({Key? key, }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ToDos> createState() => _ToDosState();
}

class _ToDosState extends State<ToDos> {
  
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          top: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 10,
          left: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 2.5,
          right: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 2.5,
          bottom: SizeConfig.screenHeight / 8
          ),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal*100,
        height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical*40,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.grey[400],
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
              border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.black45, style: BorderStyle.solid, width: 4)),
          child: Padding(
            padding:  EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                   Text(userInput)               
                ]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should do the trick. The problem was not using [`setState`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) to refresh the screen with the new data and not iterating over all values to display them (Also, moved global variables to local).

Check out the [live demo on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=5f2a0d7b9092a8b27c721c3d51176d1f)

[image]

And the code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const LandingPage(),
    );
  }
}

class LandingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LandingPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LandingPage> createState() => _LandingPageState();
}

class _LandingPageState extends State<LandingPage> {
  String userInput = "";
  var toDoList = <String>[];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Center(child: Text("To-Do-App")),
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [ToDos(list: toDoList), ToDoAdd()],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Column ToDoAdd() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding:
              const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20),
          child: TextField(
            onChanged: (value) => setState(() => userInput = value),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              hintText: "Add a new ToDo",
            ),
          ),
        ),
        MaterialButton(
          color: Colors.redAccent,
          onPressed: () => setState(() => toDoList.add(userInput)),
          child: const Text(
            "Admit",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        Text(userInput)
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ToDos extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> list;
  const ToDos({
    Key? key,
    required this.list,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ToDos> createState() => _ToDosState();
}

class _ToDosState extends State<ToDos> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          top: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 10,
          left: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 2.5,
          right: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 2.5,
          bottom: SizeConfig.screenHeight / 8),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 100,
        height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 40,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.grey[400],
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
              border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.black45, style: BorderStyle.solid, width: 4)),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(children: [
              for (final value in widget.list)
                Text(value),
            ]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SizeConfig {
  static late MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
  static late double screenWidth;
  static late double screenHeight;
  static late double blockSizeHorizontal;
  static late double blockSizeVertical;
  static late double _safeAreaHorizontal;
  static late double _safeAreaVertical;
  static late double safeBlockHorizontal;
  static late double safeBlockVertical;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
    blockSizeHorizontal = screenWidth / 100;
    blockSizeVertical = screenHeight / 100;
    _safeAreaHorizontal =
        _mediaQueryData.padding.left + _mediaQueryData.padding.right;
    _safeAreaVertical =
        _mediaQueryData.padding.top + _mediaQueryData.padding.bottom;
    safeBlockHorizontal = (screenWidth - _safeAreaHorizontal) / 100;
    safeBlockVertical = (screenHeight - _safeAreaVertical) / 100;
  }
}
```